# Update Product Table with subtable. Razor code and update code of controller is working fine but [HTTPPOST] code is not working, giving errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, controller

```
@foreach (var sprd in ViewBag.subProduct)
                       {
                            <div class="form-row control-group row-fluid">
                                <div class="controls span2">
                                    <select id="text" style="visibility: hidden;"></select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="controls span2">
                                    @sprd.subproduct_pricetitle
                                    @Html.Hidden("title1", (string)@sprd.subproduct_pricetitle)
                                </div>
                                @Html.Hidden("subid", (int)@sprd.subproduct_id)
                                <div class="controls span2">
                                    <div class="input-prepend input-append row-fluid">
                                        <span class="add-on prepend ">&pound; </span>
                                        @Html.TextBox("combined-input1", (decimal)@sprd.subproduct_price, new { @class = "row-fluid" })
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
```

This is a code for displaying the data on view page.

```
 public ActionResult Update(int id)
    {
        IEnumerable<producttype_master> Product_Typee;
        int producttypeid = Convert.ToInt32(context.product_master.Find(id).product_type.ToString());
        Product_Typee = context.producttype_master.ToList();
        ViewBag.productType = new SelectList(Product_Typee, "producttype_id", "producttype_name", producttypeid);

        IEnumerable<product_master> products;
        products = context.product_master.ToList();
        //List<subproduct_master> sprdList = context.subproduct_master.Where(m => m.product_id == id).ToList();
        IEnumerable<subproduct_master> sprdList = context.subproduct_master.Where(m => m.product_id == id).ToList();
        ViewBag.subProduct = sprdList;

        return View(context.product_master.Find(id));
    }
```

This update code is not working well, giving error.
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Update(product_master prdmaster, subproduct_master subprdmaster, FormCollection formCollection)
        {

```
        product_master prd = context.product_master.Where(m => m.product_id == prdmaster.product_id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (prd != null)
        {
            prd.product_type = int.Parse(formCollection["PrdType"]);
            prd.product_updateby = 1;
            prd.product_updateon = DateTime.Now;
            prd.product_isactive = "1";

            subproduct_master sprdList = context.subproduct_master.Where(m => m.product_id == prd.product_id).FirstOrDefault();
           if (sprdList != null)
            {

                //string latestId = context.product_master.Max(p => p.product_id).ToString();

                for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
                { 
                    subproduct_master sprdList2 = context.subproduct_master.Where(m => m.subproduct_id == sprdList.subproduct_id).FirstOrDefault();
                    sprdList2.subproduct_price = decimal.Parse(formCollection["combined-input" + i]);
                    sprdList2.subproduct_pricevalidity = Convert.ToDateTime(formCollection["datepicker1"]);
                    sprdList2.subproduct_updatedon = DateTime.Now;
                    sprdList2.subproduct_updatedby = 1;
                    sprdList2.subproduct_isactive = "1";
                    context.Entry(sprdList2).CurrentValues.SetValues(sprdList);
                    //context.SaveChanges();
                    sprdList2.subproduct_id++;
                }

            }
           context.Entry(prd).CurrentValues.SetValues(prdmaster);
           context.SaveChanges();

      }
        return View(prdmaster);
        }
```